# SDWebImage + UITableViewCell, wrong image when scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdwebimage

i'm having an issue using SDWebImage to load images to a UIImageView inside a custom UITableViewCell.
This is my code at the UITableView delegate:

```
    static NSString *userTableId = @"userTableId";
    UserDetailsTableViewCell *cell = (UserDetailsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:userTableId];
    NSDictionary *user = [userList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger position = indexPath.row + 1;
    [cell.userDetailsView loadFromDictionary:user WithIndex:position ForCharitie:false];
        cell.userDetailsView.delegate = self;

    cell.userDetailsView.delegate = self;
    return cell;
```

And here is my code for loadFromDictionary:

```
-(void) loadFromDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dic  WithIndex: (NSInteger) index ForCharitie: (BOOL) isCharitie{
    NSDictionary *userImageDic = [dic objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSString *url =[userImageDic objectForKey:@"url"];

    [userImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultAvatar"]];
    if ([url class] != [NSNull class]){
        [userImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultAvatar"]];
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is if i scroll down before some images finish loading. For example, let's say I see the first 8 rows, and rows 1, 2 and 3 still loading their images, now i scroll to 9-16, i see the `defaultAvatar` for all of them, and after a few seconds (i guess when images of rows 1,2 and 3 finish downloading), the images on cells 9, 10 and 11 change to the ones that belong to 1,2 and 3.
I don't know if there is a way to stop the images from downloading when i reuse the cell, or something like that.
Thank you and sorry for my English!

Comment: Is it cell.userImage or just userImage?

Comment: loadFromDictionary is a method of cell.userDetailsView, which is a custom view inside the custom UserDetailsTableViewCell. Inside that loadFromDictionary method is only userImage.

Comment: Aha I understand it now, also I am glad you have found the solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have your UITableViewDelegate set on your table, you could use the delegate method:

[`- tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)

to set the image to NULL (or the default) when your cell scrolls off screen.

And since you're using SDWebImage, canceling it could be as easy as ["`cancelCurrentImageLoad`"](http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Categories/UIImageView(WebCache).html#//api/name/cancelCurrentImageLoad) on the cell's image view.

Comment: Thank you, i added `cancelCurrentImageLoad` before calling `loadFromDictionary` every time the cell will be reused.

Comment: I am also using that library but I had no problems so far. This kind of problem happened with me when I was using dispatch and setting images inside threads, but thank you so much for your advice, it's really a nice hint. I really recommend this answer to anyone, who is having the same problem!

Comment: but there a case if cell did display and still didn't finish load image itself!
why cancel load image it?
how you can handle this case?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Override `prepareForReuse` method in your cell class and cancel all loadings there. Do not forget to call `super`

Answer (score 1):

Example of answer above. Swift 3

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (cell as! UITableViewCell).imageView.image = nil
    (cell as! UITableViewCell).imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting blank images with the accepted answer and given the images I'm loading are small, I wanted to let the images cache in the background and not cancel the load.

1. Push a unique id on the stack before your closure and check it when your closure completes
2. `prepareForReuse`

Like this:

```
func updateArtistImage(url: URL) {
        let _eventId = self.event?.id
        SDWebImageManager.shared().loadImage(with: url, options: [], progress: nil) { (image, data, error, cacheType, finished, url) in
            if self.event!.id == _eventId {
                if error == nil {
                    self.artistImageView.image = image
                } else {
                    self.artistImageView.image = UIImage(named: "error_image")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.artistImageView.image = nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad` and set `[imageView setImage:nil]` before call `sd_setImageWithURL`.

```
[imageView sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad];
```